# What does the "faster" in V$SQLSTATS mean?

Tags: sql, performance, oracle

Friends,

I'm currently brushing up on my SQL Tuning knowledge and it appears that the V$SQLSTATS view could be a useful tool to use.

My question is, the references to this view both in the documentation and an Oracle SQL Book I'm currently reading, mention that this view is "faster".

What is meant by faster? Is it updated more frequently than v$sql\v$sql_area? or is it just quicker to query this one table rather that perform a join on v$sql and v$sql_area

Here is the description from the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17110/dynviews_3069.htm#REFRN30396).

> V$SQLSTATS displays basic performance
>   statistics for SQL cursors and
>   contains one row per SQL statement
>   (that is, one row per unique value of
>   SQL_ID). The column definitions for
>   columns in V$SQLSTATS are identical to
>   those in the V$SQL and V$SQLAREA
>   views. However, the V$SQLSTATS view
>   differs from V$SQL and V$SQLAREA **in
>   that it is faster, more scalable, and
>   has a greater data retention**

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Faster" here would generally be related to the "more scalable" comment indicating that it is more efficient to query V$SQLSTATS than V$SQL or V$SQLAREA.  Since these views are commonly queried by people writing database monitoring tools or scripts, that tends to be an important consideration.  Some of the data dictionary views can be surprisingly expensive to query such that poorly written tools/ scripts can generate a substantial load on the database.  If you do that at the moment that the system is under load and you're investigating performance problems, that's obviously problematic.